# How to hide GXT's Info notification?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm using GXT's Info class inside my GWT app to display messages or notifications. To make the message a little bit sticky, i implemented my own version of Info class: I created an `InfoConfig` instance and set the number of milliseconds: `config.display(int milliseconds);`

The problem is sometimes i don't need the Info to be "sticky" so i need to hide it when i do something else: i tried to call the `hide()` method but it's not working!

My implementation of Info class:

```
public class StickyInfo extends Info {

    private static StickyInfo info = new StickyInfo();

    public StickyInfo() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onShowInfo() {
        super.onShowInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Show the message with a title for 20sec (default duration)
     * 
     * @param title
     *            the title of the message.
     * @param message
     *            the message to display.
     */
    public void show(String title, String message) {
        show(title, message, 20000); // for 20sec
    }

    /**
     * Show the message with no title for 20sec (default duration)
     * 
     * @param message
     *            the message to display.
     */
    public void show(String message) {
        show(null, message, 20000); // for 20sec
    }

    /**
     * Show the message for the specified number of milliseconds.
     * 
     * @param title
     *            the title of the message.
     * @param message
     *            the message to display.
     * @param milliseconds
     *            the number of milliseconds to display the message.
     */
    public void show(String title, String message, int milliseconds) {
        // Configuration
        InfoConfig config = new DefaultInfoConfig(title, message);
        config.setDisplay(milliseconds);
        // Formatting
        info.setStyleName("background-color:#f9ff4f;text-align:center;"
                + "border:0x solid black; padding: 3px; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;");
        info.show(config);

        // Position
        // Point p = info.position();
        // p.setY(p.getY() + 400);
        // p.setX(0);
        info.setPagePosition(info.position().getX(), 55);
    }

    /**
     * Show the message in the given position for the number of milliseconds.
     * 
     * @param title
     *            the title of the message.
     * @param message
     *            the message to display.
     * @param milliseconds
     *            the number of milliseconds to display the message.
     */
    public void show(String title, String message, int milliseconds, int pX,
            int pY) {
        // Configuration
        InfoConfig config = new DefaultInfoConfig(title, message);
        config.setDisplay(milliseconds);
        // Formatting
        info.setStyleName("background-color:#f9ff4f;text-align:center;"
                + "border:0x solid black; padding: 3px; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;");
        info.show(config);

        // Position
        // Point p = info.position();
        // p.setY(p.getY() + 400);
        // p.setX(0);
        info.setPagePosition(pX, pY);
    }
```

Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *user2043260* mentioned, i tried to override the `hide()` method with following:

```
@Override
public void hide() {
   if (info.getParent != null) {
      info.removeFromParent();
   }
}
```

And it works fine :) ! Thanks for the reminder ;)

Answer (score 2):

try @Override Hide() method
....

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that :)